# ng add is not working for ngx-bootstrap using angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

I m trying to integrate ngx-bootstrap with angular5 and trying to add its components.

```
ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component alerts
```

It's throwing error:

The specified command add is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

Comment: ng add is not supported < 6.0.0 versions of Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another method wich is installing it manually,

**Install ngx-bootstrap from npm, run this command in your project root folder**

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

**Add needed package to NgModule imports:**

```
import { AlertModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [AlertModule.forRoot(),...]
})
```

**For Bootstrap3,**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**For Bootstrap4,**

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

[[Source]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap#installation-instructions)

**UPDATE:**

[[Here is]](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-an-angular-5-cli-project-with-ngx-bootstrap/) complete implementation of Angular5 + ngx-bootstrap from scratch

Comment: I followed and integrated in my project but now i m getting this error:
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/public_api.d.ts(4,58): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap/alert'.

Comment: @dudduvenkatesh which version are you trying to install?

Comment: @dudduvenkatesh I've added referance to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

*ng add* is not available in angular 5, update to 6 or 7

Comment: `ng add ngx-bootstrap  --component datepicker` not working in Angular 10.